# Json Parsing using Async Task and BaseAdapter

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, baseadapter, android-adapter

I'm accessing http://graph.facebook.com/xyz and displaying name,id and gender in `ListView`. I don't know how to call the result from `doInBackground` and BaseAdapter.

```
public class FbMainActivity extends Activity {
Button b;
ListView lv;
DefaultHttpClient client;
HttpGet get;
HttpResponse response;
HttpEntity entity;
ArrayList<FBAccount> al;
MyAdapter adapter;
TextView tv1, tv2, tv3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fb_main);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bFAce);
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    al = new ArrayList<FBAccount>();
    adapter = new MyAdapter();
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MyOperation operation = new MyOperation();
            operation.execute();
        }
    });
}

private class MyOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(FbMainActivity.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog.setMessage("Loading....");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        get = new HttpGet("http://graph.facebook.com/somename");
        try {
            response = client.execute(get);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = entity.getContent();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line = null;
        do {
            try {
                line = reader.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            buffer.append(line);
        } while (line != null);
        String str = buffer.toString();
        FBAccount account;
        JSONObject object;
        try {
            object = new JSONObject(str);
            String id = object.getString("id");
            String name = object.getString("name");
            String gender = object.getString("gender");

            account = new FBAccount();
            account.setId(id);
            account.setName(name);
            account.setGender(gender);

            al.add(account);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return str;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.dismiss();


    }
}

private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return al.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return al.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.cust_layout, null);

        String id = al.get(position).getId();
        String name = al.get(position).getName();
        String gender = al.get(position).getGender();
        tv1.setText(id);
        tv2.setText(name);
        tv3.setText(gender);
        return layout;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize textviews  in getView() method...

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_student_sms, parent, false);
    YourModelClass model = al.get(position);

    final TextView tv1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv1.setText(model.getId());

    TextView tv2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tv2.setText(model.getName());

    TextView tv3 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    tv2.setText(model.getGender());

    return rowView;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks:) But why its not working on following code `LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
R.layout.cust_layout, null);
tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);`

Comment: Since getView()  method is responsible to creating the view for the adapter. so your layout is to be initialized in getView() method.

Answer (score 0):

use `onPostExecute` method for updating ListView after getting data from api. change your code as by calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` inside `onPostExecute` instead of `doInBackground`:

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

       // update listView here

      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

      dialog.dismiss();

    }
```

Comment: `lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
   al = new ArrayList<FBAccount>();
   adapter = new MyAdapter();
   lv.setAdapter(adapter);
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` Not working....

Comment: @DroidLearner: just use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); inside onPostExecute and check it's working or not?

Comment: here is a logcat(http://tinypic.com/r/51voqs/6) after using adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

You have wrongly initialized the `TextView` in your activity. It should be in your `getView` method of the adapter and it should be accessed with your `LinearLayout layout` instance as below:

Try to as below:

> ```
>    @Override
>     public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
>       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
>    View m_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cust_layout, parent, false);
>        tv1 = (TextView)m_view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
>        tv2 = (TextView)m_view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
>        tv3 = (TextView)m_view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
>    return m_view;
>   }
> ```

Comment: `NullPointerException` on this line    `tv1.setText(id);` @ρяσѕρєя K